# Re-implementing std::map::try_emplace() from C++17 in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

[`std::map::try_emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) seems very convenient and efficient but it's only available in C++17. Is it possible to re-implement it in C++11?

```
template <class... Args>
pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace(const key_type& k, Args&&... args);
```

Comment: You can express the same effect in C++11 using only the public interface, but potentially not as efficiently. Otherwise you need to modify your standard library implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an ordered map, you can get close to the behaviour with `lower_bound`:

```
template <class M, class... Args>
std::pair<typename M::iterator, bool>
try_emplace_m(M& m, const typename M::key_type& k, Args&&... args) {
    auto it = m.lower_bound(k);
    if (it == m.end() || m.key_comp()(k, it->first)) {
        return {m.emplace_hint(
            it, std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(k),
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), true};
    }
    return {it, false};
}
```

For an unordered map, you can't use `lower_bound`. You can replace it with `find`, and the test with `key_eq()`, to get a functional version, which will perform a repeated lookup in the case of an insertion, though. Sp speaking purely in terms of algorithmic complexity this new member function pulls more weight in the unordered case, which users cannot currently implement using only the public API. But the added convenience applies equally to both cases.

Comment: (The code I showed is actually very similar to libc++'s current implementation for C++17. In principle, implementers could provide this function at a lower level where you wouldn't need to repeat the key comparison.)

Comment: Thanks! Why do you say "close to the behaviour"? What would be different with the C++17 native version?

Comment: Ah, you preemptively answered my follow-up while I was typing it!

Comment: @Pol: Yes, if the key comparison would for some reason be really expensive (think very long, nearly equal strings?), then it might be worth working harder to avoid the second key comparison. The `lower_bound` operation is already comparing keys.

Comment: This does not implement `try_emplace` with `hint` for `map`. Current libc++ ignores user-provided hint. OTOH libstdc++ implement it by replacing `lower_bound` with internal interface. I have written some related interface to ease such. It is named `search_map` [here](https://github.com/FrankHB/YSLib/blob/master/YBase/include/ystdex/container.hpp#L935), but can be also used on other custom associative containers. I have implemented (more compact than the internal impl in libstdc++) but haven't release the overloading with hint parameter. I will commit it days (less than a week) later hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Simply search for the value before?

```
auto it = map.find(k);
if (it == map.end()){ //value does not exist
    auto newIt = map.emplace({std::move(k),std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same behavior as `try_emplace` since it will still create an intermediary `std::pair` instead of truly constructing the element in place.

Comment: I think emplace do a search too, in your case the key is looked up twice, not as efficient as `try_emplace`