# try_emplace in std::unordered_map without constructing temporary Key

Tags: c++, c++20, unordered-map

If transparent hash and key comparison functions are used with `std::unordered_map`, its [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) has since C++20 had an overload that allows calling the function without constructing an instance of the key. However, [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) does not currently have such an overload, so my understanding is that an instance of `Key` is always constructed when the function is called.

Is there any way to replicate this behaviour of `find` in a function that works somewhat like `try_emplace` or `operator[]`? In other words, I would like to retrieve the old value if one exists, or emplace a new value. I could just use a combination of `find` and `emplace` but I’m guessing that `emplace` does some unnecessary work in this case. If I had first determined a candidate location, I could pass it to [`emplace_hint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace_hint) (like with [`lower_bound` when using `std::map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34382175/856976)), but I don’t know how to get a suitable iterator when using `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: *"I could just use a combination of find and emplace but I’m guessing that emplace does some unnecessary work in this case."* - Even if it has to relocate the insertion point, it's still amortized constant.